# when converting text/string to date in postgres, random date is generated

Tags: postgresql, date, to-date

I have a text column indicating date i.e. 20170101

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET  work_date = to_date(workdate, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

I used this command to convert it as date. However, I got a odd result. I read though other existing posts but not sure what's wrong here.

```
+----------+---------------+
| workdate |   work_date   |
+----------+---------------+
| 20170211 | 2207-05-09    |
| 20170930 | 2209-04-27    |
| 20170507 | 2208-02-29    |
| 20170318 | 2207-08-24    |
+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Is that table is your expected result?

Comment: Works for me: https://imgur.com/a/uEkIaeh

Answer (score 0):

I think you must be mistaken about the data you are supplying to `to_date`.

> For example, input to these functions is not restricted by normal ranges, thus to_date('20096040','YYYYMMDD') returns 2014-01-17 rather than causing an error.

Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Note that this has been "fixed" in Postgres 10. `to_date('20096040','YYYYMMDD')` generates an error since then